# How to add hidden text on wordpress ( Hidden div ) using javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, wordpress

Alright so basically i've been searching for a way that when someone clicks a text , a scroll down menu drops down with basically more information ( Sort of like a read more ).

I little experience in Java or Jquery and im not even sure where the problem is wether it's in my functions.php or my script itself . I've done alot of research and tried alot of things but none seem to be able to help me out so i figured id make my own post .

Keep in my , i took most of the codes in templates given by other member and tried to modify the code so it works with my site, **I am trying to accomplish something similar to this site : http://www.randomsnippets.com/2011/04/10/how-to-hide-show-or-toggle-your-div-with-jquery/ the second example where there are 3 boxes and only one shows up when you click on it, However mine will simply be text instead of boxes)**

My Javascript file looks like this(as stated in comment idk what thechosenone is , my guess is when you select a box it is now known as the chosen one ) :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function (){
     $('.newboxes').each(function(index) {
          if ($(this).attr("id") == thechosenone) {
               $(this).show(200);
          }
          else {
               $(this).hide(600);
          }
     });
}(jQuery)
```

So i went ahead and modified my **function.php** and added these line of code :

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'showonlyone' );

function showonlyone() {
   wp_enqueue_script('showonlyone', get_template_directory_uri() . "/js/showonlyone.js");
}
```

As for calling the java script into my wordpress page I have no idea how to do this . The template gave me something like this :

```
<table>
   <tr>
      <td>
         <div style="border: 1px solid blue; background-color: #99CCFF; padding: 5px; width: 150px;">
            <a id="myHeader1" href="javascript:showonlyone('newboxes1');" >show this one only</a>
         </div>
         <div class="newboxes" id="newboxes1" style="border: 1px solid black; background-color: #CCCCCC; display: block;padding: 5px; width: 150px;">Div #1</div>
      </td>
      <td>
         <div style="border: 1px solid blue; background-color: #99CCFF; padding: 5px; width: 150px;">
            <a id="myHeader2" href="javascript:showonlyone('newboxes2');" >show this one only</a>
         </div>
         <div class="newboxes" id="newboxes2" style="border: 1px solid black; background-color: #CCCCCC; display: none;padding: 5px; width: 150px;">Div #2</div>
      </td>
      <td>
         <div style="border: 1px solid blue; background-color: #99CCFF; padding: 5px; width: 150px;">
            <a id="myHeader3" href="javascript:showonlyone('newboxes3');" >show this one only</a>
         </div>
         <div class="newboxes" id="newboxes3" style="border: 1px solid black; background-color: #CCCCCC; display: none;padding: 5px; width: 150px;">Div #3</div>
      </td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

**Can someone please tell me how im supposed to be calling this function and add it to a block of text ? I just want that when someone clicks on it , this box or whatever, drops down and displays additional information and when you click on another line of text this window will scroll back up and the other one will drop down .**

Comment: what is `thechosenone` variable hold

Comment: @TamilSelvan Idk it's just a name that came with the template , i modified the original code a bit to try and make it work with my site . the original script can be found in the link i gave in the post . Originally the first line of the code was             :function showonlyone(thechosenone) {

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Took me a minute but here you go:

http://jsfiddle.net/V4DTZ/

Now, for whats going on in the code:

```
<table>
   <tr>
      <td>
         <div style="border: 1px solid blue; background-color: #99CCFF; padding: 5px; width: 150px;">
            <a class="newboxes" href="#" id="newboxes1">show this one only</a>
         </div>
         <div  class ="div_newboxes" id="div_newboxes1" style="border: 1px solid black; background-color: #CCCCCC; display: block;padding: 5px; width: 150px;">Div #1</div>
      </td>
      <td>
         <div style="border: 1px solid blue; background-color: #99CCFF; padding: 5px; width: 150px;">
            <a class="newboxes" href="#" id="newboxes2" >show this one only</a>
         </div>
         <div  class ="div_newboxes" id="div_newboxes2" style="border: 1px solid black; background-color: #CCCCCC; display: none;padding: 5px; width: 150px;">Div #2</div>
      </td>
      <td>
         <div style="border: 1px solid blue; background-color: #99CCFF; padding: 5px; width: 150px;">
            <a class="newboxes" href="#" id="newboxes3" >show this one only</a>
         </div>
         <div  class ="div_newboxes" id="div_newboxes3" style="border: 1px solid black; background-color: #CCCCCC; display: none;padding: 5px; width: 150px;">Div #3</div>
      </td>
   </tr>
```

You'll see that I changed the `id` of the links to their corresponding `div`, and I added a div_ prefix on the ids of the `div`.

This way we have an easy way to select the `div` that matches with the `link`

I gave all of the `links` the same `class`, so that we can set up one `onclick` event for all of the links.

All of the `div` that contain your content also has the same `class`, so we can toggle them all at once.

Here is the jquery:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function (){
    $('.newboxes').on('click', function(){
    var div_id = "#div_" + $(this).prop('id');
        $('.div_newboxes').each(function(i, value){
                if($(value).prop('id')=== $(div_id).prop('id')){
                    $(div_id).show(200);
                }
                else{
                     $(value).hide(600);   
                }
        });
    })
}(jQuery))
```

Note that because we used an `onclick` event for all `elements` with `class = "newboxes"`
we are now able to use `this` to refer to the specific calling element. There is now no need to have `theChosenOne` variable.

Comment: The code seems like it works on the website you provided however , when i enter it in my wordpress . Everything goes to crap , the page becomes distorted and elements that shouldnt be there such as the search bar are appearing , the 3 boxes are appearing also below my footer which is extremely weird and on top of it all they don't work . I think I might have some setup issues within wordpress most likely in my function.php . How would you go about adding a new script to function.php? Other then that really great work , really appreciated!

Comment: @Jeremy I don't really work with wordpress. I'm not even sure how you would go about adding this. If you are somehow able to get ahold of the html on your wordpress page and update your original question, maybe we can figure something out.

Comment: what do you mean get ahold of the html on your wordpress page? like let's say this code script is meant to be used in the contact page , you want me to send you the entire page html code ?

Comment: @Jeremy yes, assuming you're able to edit it and update it on your page

Comment: there you go : http://goo.gl/9ISrBp Yes some of the text is in french because my website is for a french customer, but the wordpress and all the coding should be in english.

Answer (score 0):

1. When document is ready, attach event handlers to all of the elements needed
2. The event handler that is called every time a click happens on these elements

**Event Handler**

```
var ShowHideBlocks = function(){
$('.newboxes').each(function(index) {

      if ($(this).attr("id") == thechosenone) {
           $(this).show(200);
      }
      else {
           $(this).hide(600);
      }
});

}
```

**Attached to all interested elements**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function (){

  $('.newboxes').each(function(index) {
       $(this).bind('click',function(){
           thechosenone = $(this).attr(id); //thechosenone is a global variable
           ShowHideBlocks(); // Invoke the showHide method as part of anonymous handler
       });
   }
   });
}(jQuery)
```

Comment: This is a new script ? Great! Which one do i use though ? Im not sure what to do with these :/ And how do i add the script to my html page ? That's my main concern right now because i could have any script and it still wouldnt work because it's not setup properly .